# Getting updated input value for further update in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I use an Ajax form (with JQuery Validation Plugin) on my site. It works except for the following problem: if I enter something in a text field and then click on the send button, the value is updated. With each next update, however, the old value is always used. I already understand that I may have to work with .on or .keyup, but I understand how to properly integrate it into the code, after the click or outside ...

Update:
I have several fields in the form. Here is simplified code. I also noticed that after the first update of the form, no fields can be updated with newly entered values. All values remain old.

HTML:

```
<form id="org-684" class="org">
    <input class="org-name" type="text" name="name" value="" required>
    <button type="submit" class="updateOrg">Update</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.updateOrg').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest(".org").attr("id");
        id = id.split('-');
        id = id[1];
        var org_id_attr = "#org-"+id;
        var org_name = $(org_id_attr).find(".org-name").val();
        $(org_id_attr).validate({
            submitHandler: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update.php",
                    data: ({
                        id: id,
                        org_name: org_name
                    }),
                    success: function(response){
                        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                        $(org_id_attr).find(".org-name").val(result.name);
                    },
                    error: function() {

                    },
                    cache: false
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    }); 
})
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$orgId = $_POST['id'];
$orgName = $_POST['org_name'];
$select = "
SELECT 
    name
FROM 
    org
WHERE 
    id = $orgId
";
$result = $mysqli->query($select); 
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$res = array(
    'name' => $row[0]
 );
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: By the way, your PHP code is open to SQL injection. You should use MySQL prepare statements.

Comment: I didn't say anything.

Comment: Try and add a working snippet, at least the javascript part

Comment: *"All values remain old"* - the jQuery Validate plugin does not do that.   Examine your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. You just have to put the variables from the form behind the "SubmitHandler".

```
$(org_id_attr).validate({
    submitHandler: function() {
        var org_name = $(org_id_attr).find(".org-name").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
```